# Postgres-XL for windows

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql, postgres-xl

Currently I am of the assumption that Postgres-XL can be installed on Linux/Unix machines. But is there a way to install Postgres-XL on a Windows Server Machine?

If Yes, any help or resource would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Windows is not officially supported by Postgres-XL. Looking at the source shows no sign of a specific makefile for Windows (or just a makefiles for libpq or generic backend services)

Answer (score 1):

Postgres-XL does not currently compile in Windows. IIRC, this was due to the the threading that the Global Transaction Manager uses. It probably would not be difficult to buidl  the other components- the Coordinator and Datanode. In any event, some testing should be done if tried. Feel free to send me a message if you are interested in helping test it if we do a Windows build.

Comment: Is there any step by step instruction to install postresXL server in redhat 6.4? Or can you make a video of it? Thanks :-)